# displaying multiple polygon-type objects in XTK

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, vtk, xtk

My friend just introduced XTK ([www.goxtk.com](http://www.goxtk.com)) to me. Man, it is awesome.

I am now trying to visualize a VTK file which has VERTICES, LINES and POLYGONS. I notice that not all three kinds of objects can be displayed. I tried to shuffle their orders in the VTK file.  Only the last one can be displayed. I could use three separate files, but one file will be better. Any way to do that?

==== The VTK file ====

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
Cube example
ASCII

DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 8 float
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.0
1.0 0.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
0.0 1.0 1.0

VERTICES 1 6
5 0 2 3 4 7

LINES 2 6
2 1 3
2 4 2

POLYGONS 1 4
3 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Alas, what you want to do is not possible right now. From an object
oriented standpoint of view, this makes sense: if you type

```
var a = new X.object();
a.load('test.vtk');
```

you define one entity/one object/one thing in the scene.

So I am afraid that you need to split your vtk files right now.

If you find a good solution to this problem, please contribute it :)